# Koszul complex of $xy$, $yz$ and $xz$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Has anyone computed the homology of the sequence $xy$, $yz$ and $xz$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$?

Answer (score 1):

It should be straightforward to compute in Macaulay 2.

https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/

Comment: It's straightforward to compute it by hand.